# Differentiating a double integral (FKPP duality)

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, probability-distributions

How to compute

$$\vartheta=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{s-t}u^2(s,y)\phi_{x,t-s}(y)dyds$$

where $u:[0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and for $t>0$ differentiable w.r.t to $t$ and
$$\phi_{x,t}(y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{(y-x)^2}{2t}}$$
is the normal density with mean $x$ and variance $t$ ?

This problem appears in the duality of the FKPP-Equation, c.f.
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173264/branching-brownian-motion-and-the-kpp-equation/179121#179121

Bovier gave a comment about how to gain the derivative. I thought of using the Leibniz rule for parameter integration first to get

$$\vartheta = \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{t-t}u^2(t,y)\phi_{x,t-t}(y)dy +
\int_0^t\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{s-t}u^2(s,y)\phi_{x,t-s}(y)dyds$$

But $\phi_{x,0}$ would be a density for a dirac measure in $x$ which hasn't a Lebesgue-density. How to proceed instead?